# Using real-world art as inspiration for secondary worlds

Tags: culture

Apologies if this is the wrong place to post this. I was wondering about the legality (and ethics) of using real-world art installations in fantasy worldbuilding. For example:

Random Artist has some installation called, I don't know, Cactus Sundial, which is basically exactly as it sounds. In my book, remote island villagers wake up every morning to consult a magical cactus sundial. The scale and materials are different, but the object in the novel still basically follows the same description of the real physical installation, and would be recognisable as such by Random Artist.

Is this plagiarism or copyright infringement or anything? Does it make a difference if the artwork in question is a public installation (say, in a national park or something) vs being in a private collection? If there were lots of references to lots of artwork by lots of artists (although unnamed, because it's a fantasy world), would that make the situation better or worse?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. As you can read in our [help], we help you with the rules of your fictional world. For questions on how to deal with the laws of the real world, you might have better luck on Law.SE, once you define also the legislation you are interested in.

Comment: @L.Dutch Not exactly technically. The help center says that it is to help people building their world in general. Not being hit in the face by a lawyer seems like an issue you could have in this creative phase ^^. The thing that tears me though is that indeed there's a stack dedicated to law. Kerida would probably have better answers there.

Comment: @Kerida Anyhowy-how, you should tell under which country law the cactus-o-clock is made (most of the time the author's country), and from which country you publish your work. I never remember which country law apply in this case, but knowing both is crucial to answer as they can vary a lot.

Comment: Also, when in doubt, send a mail or call the artist to check with them ^^. People tend to be chiller when they learn someone else was inspired by their art , and perhaps you'll get a new friend? In any case, it's better to do this than to suffer a year-long fight in the court, even if you're guaranteed to win it. Lawsuits can be quite exhausting mentally.

Comment: Not an answer, because: not enough detail and I'm not a lawyer/solicitor but a [recent related headline](https://www.cbr.com/star-trek-discovery-wins-copyright-lawsuit-against-tardigrade-video-game/) might give you a hint. How many millions can you afford to spend on lawyers? Best to seek permission.

Comment: You can also defend yourself by enhancing the idea beyond the strict depiction from the artwork.  Perhaps the hour boundaries are demarked using rows of flowers vectoring out from the base of the cactus.  Perhaps the entire structure is encircled by border of crystals which somehow differentiate the seasons through their refractions.

Comment: This might be a better question for the Writing SE; they're probably more familiar with the legal issues surrounding such a scenario: https://writing.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7):

Ask on Law SE with more specifics, and also the place where you work/publish, where the artwork comes from, and how old it is.

- Plagiarism is an academic category, which has stricter standards than copyright. Copyright and related concepts like trade marks or patents could still be a problem for you.
- It is impossible to copyright concepts. Howard and his estate do/did own [Conan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conan_the_Barbarian), but not the concept of a broad-chested barbarian swordsperson. This example also shows the difference in national law when it comes to expiry, holding companies, etc.
- Public vs. private places do matter when it comes to taking pictures and then using them, but you sound as if you want to use vague concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Artists like to be cited by others, but not anonymously. Make sure you **inform the artist**. Never use ideas behind someone's back.

Agree with Rogue Ant's comment.. you can **ask for permission**.

Consider cooperation, too. Say, your Random Artist could e.g. design your cover (or game splash), you could pay an agreed, fixed amount for the image.. Maybe you'll get it for free, when the work gets signed, or the artist's name is mentioned in the book or game.